# Constraint Layout - Align views dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

I have 4 textviews aligned Horizontally in a Constraint Layout. Now, I am in need of to push the 3rd or 4th view to the next row and align the views from the left as 1st and 2nd view. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Please post your .xml file of constraint layout for us to review.

Comment: You may suggest any other layouts as well. 
Or you may design as you may find it useful. I do not have any specific design prepared yet since I am unable to think how can I design it.

Answer (score 0):

Try on this way

```
    <Textview
     android:id="@+id/text1"
    ....
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />
    
    <Textview
     android:id="@+id/text2"
    ....
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />
    
    <Textview
     android:id="@+id/text3"
    ....
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />
    
    <Textview
     android:id="@+id/text4"
    ....
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using Relative Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="70dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 1"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"
        android:text="Text 2"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"
        android:text="Text 3"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text3"
        android:text="Text 4"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But if you want to use ConstraintLayout, it should be work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="70dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 1"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 2"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 3"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 4"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```